# jQuery passing data between pages

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. Is there any way to retrieve the value of `booked` in another page through jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".active").click(function() {
        var booked=$(this).val();
        confirm(booked);
    });
});
```

Comment: `is there a way the retrieve booked` what do you mean?

Comment: You are missing a semi colon after `val()`

Comment: booked is a variable in the code... i need to use this value on another page..

Comment: Can you provide more details on the other page?

Comment: You can assign value of booked into hidden field and then submit the page and on other page you can retrieve value of hidden field.

Answer (score 7):

Use [cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) or HTML5 [`localStorage`](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) if its purely on the client-side.

```
localStorage.setItem('bookedStatus' + customerId, true);
```

Else use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if the data has already been submitted to server.

```
$.get('/site/getBookingStatus?customerId=' + customerId, function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```

Comment: good use of HTML5 but it is not cross browser. Not all the browser support this.

Comment: @Chicko: Did you at least research on how much support there is today for that? Almost all [modern browsers support it today](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) including mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if this is a simple string you can append with the URL of the page while navigating to another page. If this is secured data, you can encrypt the string and attach.

Your URL will be : `example.com/nextPage?x=booked`

In the next page you can get the string by decoding it as given :

```
var encodedData = window.location.href.split('=')[1];
var bookedValue = decodeURI(encodedData);
```

If you have encrypted the script, you have to decrypt in the next page.

Answer (score 2):

localStorage doesn't work well on mobile browsers. I've given up on trying to get localStorage to work on iPhone/safari. If you're not passing too much data then a simple solution is to attach the data to the url you are navigating to, using the usual **?param=** syntax:

```
// set your data in the source page 
function set_url_data(go_to_url, data) {
  new_url = go_to_url + '?data=' + data;
  window.location.href = new_url;
}

// parse your data in the destination page 
function grab_data_from_url() {
  url = window.location.href;
  data = url.split('data=').pop();
  return(data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try cookies if it is on the same domain.

You'll need to use the jQuery cookie [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) (to iron out cross browser issues).

You should try to do something like this:

1. Generate the variable on page 1.
2. Save this variable as a session cookie.
3. On page 2, you can now access the session cookie.
4. If the user directly visited page 2 without visiting page 1 you should have a default value setup.
5. Done!

Comment: I used 
$.post("test.php", function(data) {
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
 });
thank you guys.